# Enum case 'country' is not a member of type 'RegisterViewController.options?' why is it so?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to change datasource array of tableview according to the button clicked.
I use enumeration method to identify or mark the button I click.

But in the code it shows an error like:

> Enum case 'country' is not a member of type 'RegisterViewController.options?'

I can't figure it out.

`options` is the enum containing 3 cases.

```
//enum declaration

enum options {
    case dawat
    case country
    case nationality
}

var lastSelection:options?
```

---

```
//code
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PIckerTableViewCell

    if isSearching == true {
        signUser.tableData = signUser.filteredArray
        cell.lblTitle.text = signUser.tableData[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        switch lastSelection { 
        case options.country:
            signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.countries
        case options.dawat:
            signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.dawatTitles
        case options.nationality:
            signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.nationalities
            signUser.tableData = signUser.unfilteredArray
            cell.lblTitle.text = signUser.tableData[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of the enum (`RegisterViewController.options`)?

Comment: need more clarification to understand your problem, will you please add the code of enum declaration in your question?

Comment: okay please wait a moment

Comment: Read the error message.  The question mark in `'RegisterViewController.options?'` indicates that `lastSelection` is an *optional* and needs to be unwrapped.

Comment: prblem still exists even after unwrapping

Comment: @JaseelCalicut: Then please show your updated code, and the exact error message.

Comment: your lastselection var is optional  you need to unwrap optional when passing to switch or you may set it to a default value like 
var lastselection:options = .country and then pass to switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either unwrap your optional property before using it

```
if let last = lastSelection {
    switch last { 
        case options.country:
            signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.countries
        //and so on...                
    }
} else {
    //?
}
```

or add a default case to your enum

```
enum options {
    case dawat
    case country
    case nationality
    case notSet
}

var lastSelection = options.notSet
```

and then use it in the switch

```
switch lastSelection { 
    //other case...
    case options.notSet:
        //?
    }
}
```

Comment: still problem exists

Answer (score -1):

hey check this answer:

```
enum  options  {
    case dawat
    case country
    case nationality
    case none

}

var lastSelection = options.none
```

[image]

Comment: Answers are more helpful if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of dumping some code only.

Comment: sure, I will improve this answer with clarification.

Comment: if i add more code..you will blame me for too much code//please dont make reasons for your helplessness

Comment: dude I have make a demo of it and its working for me please refer the the screenshot.. :)